# Write List data to csv powershell

Tags: powershell

I am getting data like below

```
Path              : C:\Program Files\ibm\gsk8\lib64
ModifiablePath    : C:\Program Files\ibm\gsk8\lib64
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
Permissions       : {WriteOwner, Delete, WriteAttributes, Synchronize...}

Path              : C:\Program Files\ibm\gsk8\bin
ModifiablePath    : C:\Program Files\ibm\gsk8\bin
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
Permissions       : {WriteOwner, Delete, WriteAttributes, Synchronize...}
```

I had to use **Fomat-List** to bring the data this way because without this the last column **Permissions** was not visible. and when I tried Export-csv for the data, the last column coming as **System.Object[]**
Please let me know how to write this data to csv

Comment: You would need to enumerate and loop over the `Permissions` properties of the objects. What have you tried?

Comment: We can't tell you, as it depends how you want to handle the `Permissions` values. Do you want one row per named permission? A semicolon-separated string in a single column?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: A single column. as it reflects the Permissions for that specific path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Select-Object` to create a new calculated property:

```
... |Select-Object Path,ModifiablePath,IdentityReference,@{Name='Permissions';Expression={$_.Permissions -join ';'}} |Export-Csv -Path path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.